# Problem booting after latest software update.

Tags: 12.04, boot, stable-release-updates

I have a Desktop i7 with an ATI HD6990. After the last update, my system is unable to boot properly. All I can access is a terminal. I can't access my files. Is everything lost?

Here is a video I have recorded:

> http://youtube.com/watch?v=apZ9zZzQQ1I

After a correct login and `sudo apt-get update`, nothing has changed. Rebooting the system makes no difference.

My question is: how can I retrieve my files?

Comment: Can you look at this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/218095#218095 and see if it helps?

Comment: In case my solution below does not work and you just want to retrieve your files, add a comment in my answer. I shall post the answer for retrieving your files. All your files are safe. DO NOT format your desktop yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem about 5 minutes ago (I was updating Ubuntu 13.04).
This is how I solved it:

1. When you see the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode", click on "OK"
2. Then you'll see "What would you like to do?". Select "Run in low-graphics mode for just one session" and click "OK".
3. You'll see the message "Stand by one minute while the display restarts...". Click "OK" and wait. DO NOT touch anything (especially the power button). Just wait for the display to come up.
4. You will enter a terminal-like mode. The last word in that text mode will be "Login". Type in your user-name and press Enter.
5. It will then ask you for your password. Type in your login password and press Enter (no text will be displayed when you type your password. It will be blank. But don't worry. Everything is working fine).
6. If your user-name and password were correct, you'll be logged in. (if not, type them in again).
7. Now you need to type "sudo reboot" and press Enter.
8. Wait for your desktop to restart. Your desktop will then work just fine.

Comment: Since it worked for you, please click on the "^" (beside my answer, above the "0"). This will let others know that the solution provided works.

Comment: I am cant see your ^^^^ thing on mobile page ..... Where is it ? Beside your aswer the field is wery empty.

Comment: May be you can vote up you log in using your laptop/desktop.
If you go to this link http://ubuntuone.com/27IIDFOJxQ2cm3UIyZVWJm
you'll see exactly where the vote up button is.

Comment: U mean voting up ?
I am unable to vote up, MORE (15) reputation points needed !!!